# MethodHandles.lookup().defineClass retention

Tags: java, java-9

[`MethodHandles.Lookup.defineClass`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.Lookup.html#defineClass-byte:A-) generates a new class from a byte array at runtime.

Under what circumstances can the returned class be garbage collected?  Is it retained for the lifetime of the classloader associated with the `Lookup` object, or can it be garbage collected if the `Class` object is no longer referenced?

Comment: According to the documentation; _"Defines a class to the same class loader ... as this lookup's lookup class."_, so I'd assume it's collected when the class loader is, just like a regular class loaded by a class loader.

Comment: @JornVernee The class has a name right? I don't think that's been changed (might be wrong). If it's got a name it can be looked up and so needs to be reachable from the `ClassLoader` instance.

Comment: I wouldn't actually expect a class defined with defineClass to be lookuppable from a name.

Comment: The class defined with Lookup.defineClass is just a regular class so it can't be GC'ed before its defining class loader. There isn't anything like VM anonymous classes in the standard API at this time.

Comment: @LouisWasserman The `byte[]` that you pass to `defineClass` is just a class file, which includes a name. So you can look it up from that name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The classes created via `MethodHandles.Lookup.defineClass` are registered at the defining class loader like any other class and can be referenced by name like ordinary classes, in contrast to [`defineHiddenClass(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.Lookup.html#defineHiddenClass(byte%5B%5D,boolean,java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles.Lookup.ClassOption...)) introduced with JDK 15 (see the end of the answer). They may even supersede statically compiled classes when being registered before those classes have been resolved, like with the following example:

```
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class LookupDynamicClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalAccessException {
        MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
        lookup.defineClass(("Êþº¾\0\0\0005\0\26\11\0\11\0\12\10\0\13\12\0\14\0"
        +"\15\7\0\16\7\0\17\1\0\3foo\1\0\3()V\1\0\4Code\7\0\20\14\0\21\0\22\1\0"
        +"\30hello from dynamic class\7\0\23\14\0\24\0\25\1\0\4Lazy\1\0\20java/"
        +"lang/Object\1\0\20java/lang/System\1\0\3out\1\0\25Ljava/io/PrintStream;"
        +"\1\0\23java/io/PrintStream\1\0\7println\1\0\25(Ljava/lang/String;)V\6\0"
        +"\0\4\0\5\0\0\0\0\0\1\0\11\0\6\0\7\0\1\0\10\0\0\0\25\0\2\0\0\0\0\0\11²\0"
        + "\1\22\2¶\0\3±\0\0\0\0\0\0").getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));

        Lazy.foo();
    }
}
interface Lazy {
    static void foo() {
    }
}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##bVLNitswEL77KURONqWKrayTLaGHNhS6kGULgV7qsmhtxVEiS8ZS0qZlX2Dfpj300MMevA@WjiQnOKE29sjffPN5/tZ0R1@vi83hwKtaNQatAcCCyhJzuVMbhm@ZWaniI5WFYHoa9GmSK5yvaKOZwQsDDNoUM/8NzCAXVGt0S7lEPwMEV719EDxH2lADZqd4gSrwhgvTcFl@@YpoU@oImVWjvml0IwQrqXiX50zrD99zVhuujlL2OssMz5XabGskvHl74fVwGE1P0R7BBVtyyWY21TAcvDy9PLd/2@cstnccp2DIOEsSsP5FssT6kpE9gr3K4sFJ89UgS9JsYvGxN5PMRo2WSvlDGH12h6uZKpijEC@SEQsTYr1ngqN4xYRQaNmoChV7SSvonWutDx914e6VevE5/bF3JxLbQQ37gna2w7uHNctNn@LgxV4bVvlM1bbzp3NH4Gr4CcZkYFiMVtPzol0i/6E5z6S2gJCdXDjv/dBNfgpNGV@UDVXAk/pBuPs0g7HVPAJHL3Gj6tOT9veZJrJ5QoNJ@8fW1/7qkeNBhEtm3u8N0@HlKuObxd399XX65j6JYIFOirbLGCZ73KrH4DGAQlmzpDlz3m5Z@wvv@B0OAYfDPw)

This example dynamically defines a `Lazy` class whose `foo()` method will print `hello from dynamic class` when being invoked.

On JVMs like HotSpot, where the symbolic reference “`Lazy`” gets resolved lazily, i.e. right when the attempt to invoke `Lazy.foo()` is made, this will end up at the dynamically defined class. For JVMs eagerly resolving symbolic references, the `Lazy` class would already exist when `MethodHandles.Lookup.defineClass` is invoked and therefore, a `LinkageError` with a message like “attempted duplicate definition for Lazy” will be thrown.

In other words, these dynamically generated classes share the same name space (class loading context) as the statically compiled classes. Being registered at the class loader like an ordinary class, they can only get garbage collected when the defining class loader becomes unreachable (including all of its defined classes), like with ordinary classes.

---

JDK 15 introduced [`defineHiddenClass(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.Lookup.html#defineHiddenClass(byte%5B%5D,boolean,java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles.Lookup.ClassOption...)) which can be used to define classes not registered at a class loader and also capable of accessing `private` members of the lookup class, similar to the older non-standard feature `sun.misc.Unsafe.defineAnonymousClass`.

The behavior is controlled by the [`ClassOption`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.Lookup.ClassOption.html) parameter(s).

- `NESTMATE` enables access to `private` members of the lookup class and its nest members (typically inner classes)
- `STRONG` prevents the class from being unloaded until the class loader became unreachable, though I have no idea why anyone should ever want this. Without this option, the hidden class can get garbage collected and unloaded as soon as no reference to it exists.

Here is an adapted version of the example:

```java
public class LookupHiddenClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        var lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
        lookup = lookup.defineHiddenClass(("Êþº¾\0\0\0005\0\26\11\0\11\0\12\10\0\13\12"
        +"\0\14\0\15\7\0\16\7\0\17\1\0\3foo\1\0\3()V\1\0\4Code\7\0\20\14\0\21\0\22\1\0"
        +"\27hello from hidden class\7\0\23\14\0\24\0\25\1\0\4Lazy\1\0\20java/"
        +"lang/Object\1\0\20java/lang/System\1\0\3out\1\0\25Ljava/io/PrintStream;"
        +"\1\0\23java/io/PrintStream\1\0\7println\1\0\25(Ljava/lang/String;)V\6\0"
        +"\0\4\0\5\0\0\0\0\0\1\0\11\0\6\0\7\0\1\0\10\0\0\0\25\0\2\0\0\0\0\0\11²\0"
        + "\1\22\2¶\0\3±\0\0\0\0\0\0").getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1), true);

        lookup.findStatic(lookup.lookupClass(), "foo", MethodType.methodType(void.class))
              .invokeExact();

        var q = new ReferenceQueue<Class<?>>();
        var r = new PhantomReference<>(lookup.lookupClass(), q);

        lookup = null;

        do System.gc(); while(q.remove(1000) != r);

        System.out.println("class collected");
    }
}
```

While there’s no guaranty that `System.gc()` will perform an actual garbage collection nor that it does collect a particular object, with OpenJDK’s default configuration it reproducibly prints

```
hello from hidden class
class collected
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  That's actually a little disappointing to me, as I expected it to work more or less like MethodHandles themselves which are runtime-generated _and garbage collectable_ (AFAIK) program logic.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I know what you mean. Like an official alternative to `Unsafe.defineAnonymousClass`. Unfortunately, this is not the case (and there is no official API for such a feature).

Comment: @Holger well if such an official way were provided, wouldn't it mean that we could have hacked into any class we wanted?

Comment: @LouisWasserman Maybe something like that will be available in the future: https://youtu.be/-k_IicifbxQ?t=2375 (_"Because a class is non-findable, it can be unloaded even when the class loader is still alive"_)

Comment: @JornVernee Ah.  I was at that talk, but evidently didn't pay enough attention.

Comment: @Eugene we’re not talking about overriding access control, but about the anonymous natures of the classes created by that method. The official API could check the access, just like this `MethodHandles.Lookup.defineClass` does.

Comment: Update: [the official alternative to `sun.misc.Unsafe::defineAnonymousClass`](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/371) is target for JDK 15.

Comment: @Eugene finally, the official alternative to `Unsafe.defineAnonymousClass` became reality and it does allow access to `private` members similar to the nonstandard predecessor. But since the lookup object needs to have the private access rights to the target class already, this doesn’t introduce more hacking possibilities.

Comment: @Holger I can't wait to try it! Many thanks for pinging me