# Why does OnlineJudge, such as codeforces and leetcode, not allow java submit to self built classloader?

Tags: java, classloader, java-security

For example, when

```
new classloader() {};
```

**Java.security.accesscontrolexception** will be thrown. Is there any risk that OJ allows submitters to build their own classloader? Is there any alternative for function defineclass()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Security policies are associated with code locations. Since a `ClassLoader` can specify the code location for the classes it defines, it could dodge restrictions applying to its own code location.

When you use [`MethodHandles.lookup().defineClass(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.Lookup.html#defineClass(byte%5B%5D)) you can only create classes within your own context, hence, not use it to expand your privileges. Therefore, you can use it even when a security manager is installed, as long as your lookup object has the necessary [full privileges](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.Lookup.html#hasFullPrivilegeAccess()).

So, when I run the example of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52719236/2711488) under JDK 14 or newer with the
`-Djava.security.manager` option, it runs smoothly without requiring any permissions.

So when the mentioned online execution environments run under JDK 14 or newer, you can use this method for dynamic code generation.

Comment: Thanks! I think your answer perfectly explains why classloader was limited. I learned about the new features of classloader. Unfortunately, the OJ I use uses a lower version of JDK, so it directly prohibits any behavior of **defineclass** ("Java. Lang. runtimepermission" "defineclass"). But your answer still makes me learn a lot about the features of Java class loading. Thank you again!

Comment: Maybe, they update some day…